# Adicionar tooltip a button que veio direto do Php via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tooltip

No meu servidor PHP eu retorno alguns dados entre eles um button

```
$HTML = " <button id=\"btnExcluir\"  style=\" width: 55px !important;\" onclick=\"Excluir();\" type=\"button \"  data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"     Excluir itens selecionados\" class=\"btn   btn-danger botaoExcluir\"> " ;

echo $HTML;
```

No meu arquivo HTML/JS eu tenho minha requisição Ajax que busca esses dados do servidor Php, e inclui eles em uma div com o Id Dados ... Até então ele aparece normalmente e no meu arquivo Jquery eu tenho a seguinte função

```
$(function () {
       $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
```

Para conseguir estilizar o tooltip do meu buttom, porém ele não altera o tipo. Como é possivel adicionar esse estilo ao button?

Comment: Se é JQuery UI Tooltip que está a utilizar tem [exemplos na documentação deles de como estilizar os balões](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style), que envolvem criar classes de css e indica-las na chamada à função `tooltip`, se é que percebi corretamente a sua questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque todo elemento html que entra dinamicamente não faz parte do **[DOM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_de_Objeto_de_Documentos)** inicial que foi carregado no documento atual. Para que seja possível selecionar esses elementos você deve utilizar alguns métodos do jquery específicos para isto.

Você pode pesquisar um pouco mais sobre esses métodos na documentação do jquery:

[Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) e [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), bons estudos! ;)

Ex com 'on'.

```
$(document).on('change', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function() {
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

Ex com delegate com evento click:

```
$(".divpai").delegate( "elementofilho", "click", function() {
    $(this).css({display:"none"});
});
```